# Are floating point numbers denormalised before the processor performs arithmetic operations on them?

Tags: fpga, computer-architecture, alu, floating-point

Does the processor denormalise the numbers in IEEE 754 notation and normalise the result after storing or are the arithmetic operations performed on the numbers as they are?
I'm asking because in case of multiplication, let's say the exponents (denorm.) are e1 and e2. the normalised exponents in, say, single precision would be e1+127 and e2+127, the addition of which will lead to e1+e2+254, whereas what we want the final notation to be is e1+e2+127.
TIA.

Comment: Which processor, specifically?  I most likely won't be able to answer this question, but for _anyone_ to be able to answer it, we need to know which processor you're asking for, as some families of processors use different algorithms with floating point operations than other families.

Answer (score 1):

For multiplication, you simply multiply the mantissas and add the exponents, with a possible small adjustment to renormalize the result. There's no need to denormalize anything first.

For addition/subtraction, it is necessary to align the numbers, which means making their exponents equal before dealing with the mantissas. The number with the smaller exponent is denormalized in order to line things up. Obviously, if the difference in exponents is greater than the width of the mantissa, there's no point in completing the operation — the smaller number becomes effectively zero.

Don't confuse denormalization with the fact that the exponents are stored in "excess-128" notation. That's a completely separate issue. Yes, you need to convert that to 2's-complement before you do arithmetic on the exponents.

Answer (score -2):

It of course depends on the operation. For addition, there's no point. The binary result does not depend on the interpretation of the exponent field. For multiplication, you need only a small adder. If you want fast multiplication, you can't wait on a general-purpose 32 bits adder. You'll have a dedicated adder for the exponent field in multiplication, and that adder can apply the normalization in hardware, in constant time.

CPU's that have a sin/cos operation can typically ignore most exponent values. Either the exponent is so small that `sin(x)=x` or the result is meaningless. For the small range of exponents near 1.0 where `sin(x)` is non-trivial, you can convert to fixed-point.

Comment: Two things: I think you have the issues regarding addition and multiplication mixed up. And how do trig operations have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @DaveTweed: I'm pretty sure I didn't; I've written software emulation. Remember that floating point numbers have the format `mantissa * 2 ^(exponent-bias)` so multiplication amounts to `m1*m2*2 ^(exp1-bias +exp2-bias)`. That's why FP multiplication requires an adder for the exponent bits, with a correction for the bias. (And a carry from the mantissa multiplication)

Comment: Yes, multiplication requires an exponent adder, but that has nothing to do with the question about denormalization.

Comment: As for trig operations, there are CPU's that do have trig instructions. x87 has `FSIN`, `FCOS` and even `FSINCOS`. Since the question didn't mention specific arithmetic instructions, I took trig instructions as a non-trivial example. Square root would have been another non-trivial instruction.

Comment: @DaveTweed: The question is specifically mentioning the whole `e1+e2+254` versus the desired `e1+e2+127`. How is that _not_ the exponent adder ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the OP is using the term "denormalization" incorrectly. We'll just have to wait and see whether they come back and clarify.